# Unable to loop through terms in Timber

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber, taxonomy-terms

***WordPress Version: 4.8.2

Timber Version: 1.5.0***

First off, I've spent a lot of time off in Craft CMS land and have been away from Wordpress/Timber for a while now! As a result, I'm sure this problem is of my own doing but I just can't see where/how/why.

**What I'm trying to do:**

In my `archive-portfolio.php` file I am trying to get and set terms that belong to a specific custom taxonomy:

`$context['terms'] = Timber::get_terms('work-category');`

In `templates/archive-portfolio.twig` I am trying to loop through these terms to make a horizontal menu of terms so the user can use them to filter portfolio items:

```
<ul class="menu">
    {% for term in terms %}
        <li>{{term.name}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**What I actually get:**

The result is this error repeated four times at the top of the page:

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/Steven/.../wp-content/plugins/timber-library/lib/TermGetter.php on line 82`

Dumping `terms` just gives me a wp error object.

**The real question**

Where is my error? Am I trying to get the terms incorrectly in my `php` file, or am I trying to loop through them incorrectly in my `twig` file?

Thanks!

Comment: Is not an issue with `Twig`, are you sure the terms `work-category` exist?

Comment: Oh dear lord. In `functions.php` I created it as `portfolio-category` and was trying to call `work-category`. *finds rock to crawl under*

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out beneath that rock of yours :D